# Sending an SMS message with GSM cell phone yields Generic Comm Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am taking help from the following link:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx

I have Downloaded source and ran this code on my machine but it is giving an error “Error: Phone reports generic communication error or syntax error”. I'm using the nokia 2690 and I have connected it to my laptop with a data cable in the USB port.

Comment: Can you provide a logs for communication between laptop and phone? This will help to find cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which .Net Framework you are Using..?

It will supports/requires .Net 2.0/1.1.

Check it.Please otherwise Gothrough this link.

http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/samples.htm

Hope this may helpful.

Comment: Please Visit this Link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.     since it seems you have not yet discovered how to accept answers